# Open Child Form in Parent Form's Panel from Another Child Form

Tags: c#, winforms, github, parent-child

i am new in c# windows application learning

i have 3 form.
**main form, form menu, child form**

in **main form** when i click on **button1**, **form menu** is show in **1st panel**.

```
this code in main form.....this work properly for me... if anyone have better then this then suggest me. 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool IsOpen = false;
            foreach (Form frmchild in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (frmchild.Text == "Child Form")
                {
                    IsOpen = true;
                    frmchild.Close();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (IsOpen == false)
            {
                child form cf = new child form();
                cf.Owner = this;    //main form is owenr
                cf.Show();
                cf.Location
                    = new Point(button1.Left + 37, button1.Height + button1.Top + 4);
            }
        }
```

**main form** have **2 panel**, **1st** is small and dock in top. **2nd** is main panel (dock = fill) where i want to dock all **child form**.

in **form menu** i have button and when i click on i want to **open child form in main form 2nd panel**.

`please help me to open child form in main form's panel when i click button in another child form in c# language.`

please help me.

Answer (score -1):

i think you have to use USER CONTROL instead of a form. Add a usercontrol at your prject and here is the code :

```
        for (int i = panel2.Controls.Count; i > 0; i--)
        {
                panel2.Controls[i-1].Dispose();
        }

        //add user control you want
        UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
        panel2.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Comment: Of course you don't use the `Remove()` (`or Clear()`) method, but instead `Dispose()` of each  Control (or UserControl) in the collection, otherwise those Controls remain very well *alive*. --  A backwards loop is commonly used for this (so you don't modify the collection you're iterating over, since disposing of a Control also removes it from the `Controls` collection)

Comment: Yeah. I made correction. thanks